# Bokeh/Jupyter Notebook: Charts don't render when downloaded as HTML

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

My general practice when sharing Jupyter notebooks has been to download them as HTML and hide the code blocks - this works well because it preserves the interactive aspects of the Bokeh charts.

After I recently updated Bokeh, none of the charts I am creating are visible when I download a Jupyter notebook as HTML.  I am running Bokeh 0.12.1, Python 3.5, and iPython 5.1.0.  Any solutions to this issue?

Update: regressing to Bokeh 0.11.1 and iPython 5.0.0 resolves this issue, and also resolves other ongoing issues around needing to run output_notebook() multiple times.

Comment: Add Jupyter console output while rendering the notebook to HTML

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this and how to do it?

Comment: When I start IPython notebook from bash console on Ubuntu Linux I can see program output in this console window. When I had problems while exporting notebooks to HTML I could see program output related to missing dependencies or program misfunction like exceptions or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Bokeh to display anything at all, the BokehJS client library must be loaded. BokehsJS is loaded by the JavaScript code that is executed in the notebook output cell for `output_notebook`. If you hide the cell containing `output_notebook` is hidden, the code to load BokehJS is never run, BokehJS is not loaded, and no Bokeh plots will display.

Long story short: you can't hide the cell that calls `output_notebook`

See [this issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4859#issuecomment-308192079) for further discussion, as well as a possible alternative to hiding using "notes" cells (it's mentioned there but I don't know anything more about it)